# How to use Feasopt with docplex python api?

Tags: python, optimization, diagnostics, mixed-integer-programming, docplexcloud

I'm using the docplex.mp.model module to run a mixed-integer-programming problem when I ended up receiving an infeasible solution?
Is there any way I could use the Feasopt in order to repair my model?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify what an "infeasible solution" is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

DOcplex has a `Relaxer` class that is more general than feasopt.
See this example notebook for details about handling infeasible models:

https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/infeasible.ipynb